# Remove Duplicate Rows in Oracle Table

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I want to do a SQL in Toad to extract all the values of a tables whits some conditions. I catch all the values but now I want add a new condition to the SQL but I don't know how. I want only catch the values that aren't duplicates. For example:

I have now this:

```
PRINCIPAL APELLIDO NOMBRE
a           b        c
b           c        d
c           d        e
a           l        m
```

In this case I want only catch the values that `PRINCIPAL` is not duplicated, in the example I want to catch only the second and the third row because the first and the fourth are duplicated.

Answer (score 3):

One way is you could use this query:

```
SELECT principal,
    MAX(apellido) AS apellido,
    MAX(nombre) AS nombre 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY principal
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY principal;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a sub-query that returns PRINCIPAL values existing more than once:

```
select *
from tablename
where PRINCIPAL not in (select PRINCIPAL from tablename
                        group by PRINCIPAL
                        having count(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [`COUNT`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions046.htm#SQLRF00624) aggregated function for the removing of all of the duplicated rows.

```
select PRINCIPAL, APELLIDO, NOMBRE,
count(*) over (partition by PRINCIPAL) dup_cnt
from tab

P A N    DUP_CNT
- - - ----------
a b c          2
a l m          2
b c d          1
c d e          1
```

The `COUNT` count the rows for each unique key defined in the `PARTITION BY` clause.

The final query selects only the unique rows, i.e. rows with  `DUP_CNT = 1`

```
with dedup as (
select PRINCIPAL, APELLIDO, NOMBRE,
count(*) over (partition by PRINCIPAL) dup_cnt
from tab)
select PRINCIPAL, APELLIDO, NOMBRE
from dedup
where dup_cnt = 1
```

Note: using [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions170.htm#SQLRF06100) instead of `COUNT` you can do deduplication, i.e. you let one of the duplicated rows in the result and remove the duplicates.

**Note** that this method requires a *sort* of the table (`WINDOW SORT`), which may be heavy for large tables. In this case a method using `NOT EXISTS` may yield better performance, as it is transformed and performed as anti hash join - `HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI`.

```
select principal, apellido, nombre 
from tab t
where not exists 
(select null
 from tab 
 where  principal = t.principal and rowid <> t.rowid
)
```

Some care must be taken if the deduplication column (`principal`) is nullable. Contrary to the first solution with `COUNT` the `not exusts` leaves all the `null`s in the result. If this is not required you must add a filter:

```
 and t.principal is not NULL
```

If you have an index on the `pricipal` column, the optimal execution plan looks as follows

```
--------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name | 
--------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |      |    
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI |      |     
|   2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| IDX  |  
|*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL   | TAB  |  
--------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("PRINCIPAL"="T"."PRINCIPAL")
       filter(ROWID<>"T".ROWID)
   3 - filter("T"."PRINCIPAL" IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch @Boneist I re-read the question and updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions.  The logic would be:

```
select principal, apellido, nombre
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by principal) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

This will return rows where `principal` is `NULL`; such rows are eliminated by `NOT EXISTS`.

However, the fastest method if you have a primary key and an index on `(principal, pk)` is probably:

```
select principal, apellido, nombre
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.principal = t.principal and t2.pk <> t.pk
                 );
```

Comment: Good intuition for the (probably) most performant solution, but please note that while using `not exists` some care should be taken if the column is *nullable*.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber . . . No, not really any care at all.  It generally behaves as intended.  `NOT IN` on the other hand, has very unexpected behavior.

Comment: My point was if you add two rows with `principal is null` in the table they are eliminated with the `count` approach, but accepted with the `not exists` query. So the two queries behave not identical - therefore the care.